# Angular: clean way to bind template var based on active routerlink

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routerlink, routerlinkactive

Building an Angular 4 app, but I would accept an answer that works with v5+ as well.  I have a navbar composed of navigation buttons like this:

```
<custom-button routerLink="/some-route"></custom-button>
```

I know I can add a custom class *"active"* to the element based on whether the current route matches the button's `routerLink` with:

```
<custom-button routerLink="/some-route" routerLinkActive="active"></custom-button>
```

However I need a way to bind an input value based on this condition (whether the route is current), like:

```
<custom-button routerLink="/some-route" [inputFlag]="isOnCurrentRoute">
</custom-button>
```

So the idea is that `inputFlag` would be set to `true` if the button's `routerLink` refers to the current route.  I know this could be accomplished by injecting `ActivatedRoute` and building a function that takes the value of the button's `routerLink` and returns `true` if it matches the current route.

```
<custom-button routerLink="/some-route" 
  [inputFlag]="isOnCurrentRoute('/some-route')">
</custom-button>
```

That's a lot of overhead though; wondering if Angular exposes an API to do all that within the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kept thinking about it and if Angular does have a feature of doing what you were looking for `routerLinkActive` attribute in conjunction to `routerLink` we can use it to hack a little bit just in the template itself and no JS/TS code, by checking the class name which gets assigned by `routerLinkActive`.

Solution:

```
<custom-button #customBtn
  routerLink="/some-route" 
  routerLinkActive="active"
  [inputFlag]="customBtn.classList.contains('active')"
></custom-button>
```

Comment: that's really clever.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function isOnCurrentRoute like this

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

isOnCurrentRoute(path): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(event => event.url === path)
  );
}
```

and use it on your template with an async pipe

```html
<custom-button routerLink="/some-route" 
  [inputFlag]="isOnCurrentRoute('/some-route') | async">
</custom-button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks for your response.  I am able to design such a function just fine.  In fact I hint at a(nother) way to do this in the OP.  My question is whether Angular offers a seamless way to do it entirely in the template